# Is castration permitted in Islam

Tags: fiqh, history

I know that in the Ottoman Caliphet, the janissaries were castrated, so was castration permitted according to Sharia Law

Comment: I've never heard  janisessaries were being castrated. Perhaps you're confusing them with eunuchs ? Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eunuch#Ottoman_Empire

Answer (score 2):

Castration is totally prohibited in Islam, either for slaves or free men .

Stated in the hadith :

> عن عبد الله بن مسعود قال : كنا نغزو مع رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ،
> وليس لنا شيء ، فقلنا : ألا نستخصي ؟ فنهانا عن ذلك . رواه البخاري (
> 4787 ) ومسلم (1404)
>
> Narrated Ibn Masud: We used to fight in the holy battles in the
> company of the Prophet (ﷺ) and we had nothing (wives) with us. So we said, "O
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Shall we get castrated?" The Prophet (ﷺ)
> forbade us to do so.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari, Book of Marriage](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/13) & [Muslim, Book of Marriage](http://sunnah.com/muslim/16/13-15)</sup>

Comment: What numbering scheme does your Bukhari 4787 reference use? Because that's coming up as a completely unrelated hadith here: http://sunnah.com/urn/44650