# Is castration an allowed punishment in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, punishment, hudud

Refer to here, which says that [castration is prohibited in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/32641/4503):

> عن عبد الله بن مسعود قال : كنا نغزو مع رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ،
> وليس لنا شيء ، فقلنا : ألا نستخصي ؟ فنهانا عن ذلك . رواه البخاري (
> 4787 ) ومسلم (1404)
>
> Narrated Ibn Masud: We used to fight in the holy battles in the
> company of the Prophet (ﷺ) and we had nothing (wives) with us. So we said, "O
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Shall we get castrated?" The Prophet (ﷺ)
> forbade us to do so.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari, Book of Marriage](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/13) & [Muslim, Book of Marriage](http://sunnah.com/muslim/16/13-15)</sup>

However, another Islamic website says that surgical castration [is a valid punishment for rape](http://www.islamandquran.org/fatwas/punishment-for-rape.html):

> Since the perpetrator has forcibly harmed an organ, which is legally
> and ethically forbidden to be touched,  he deserves his organs being
> harmed. The damage caused by the perpetrator will influence the
> aggrieved party till the end of her life. Due to this characteristic
> of the crime, the punishment on the perpetrator must also be
> permanent. The only punishment with this characteristic is surgical
> castration. Therefore, punishment for rape is surgical castration.

So which is true? Or there is no consensus on this matter?

Comment: Relevant: [What are the Islamic rulings on Rape?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/44167/20218). The website you are referring to does not cite any sources and uses their own reasoning to arrive at their conclusion.

Comment: Brother, rape is pure corruption in the land, and punishment for the worst types of corruptions such as rape etc. Is death, so i don't knowwho you got this tsatement from, but eye for an eye is not how islam works in all cases.

Comment: So please try to get better information.

Answer (score 1):

I found no Sahih hadith regarding the subject, but I have found several Hasan hadith that all go along the lines of this:

> "Whoever kills his slave, we will kill him: whoever mutilates (his slave). We will mutilate him, and whoever castrates (his slave), we will castrate him." ([Sunan an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/45/31))

So, if we use these hadith, we can say that castration can be a punishment for forced castration of others. But, there is no evidence that this can be for rape. The punishment for that is death by most schools of thought.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that No it is not allowed because there is only one valid punishment for rape, and it is death-

Mainly because rape is nothing but spreading mischief and corruption in the land and stealing the honour of a woman, and leading it to become a problem if she intends to get married in the future, because:

*1.* The word that she got raped by a man may spread among the people, and that may affect her future marital life in the sense that it may become difficult for her or her family to find a spouse for her who is willing to marry her after he has heard of what has happened.

*2*. she may get pregnant and face difficulties and problems in the future of taking care of her child, and as far as i am concerned, society won't react positively towards this and may even isolate that family from themselves, or mke her an outcast, or to even maybe get her killed ( in some countries ) to keep their status and name and etc.

And many many other problems. End quote.

Nextly: Allaah made a clear punishment for the one who spreads mischief and corruption in the land:

> “The recompense of those who wage war against Allaah and His Messenger and do mischief in the land is only that they shall be killed or crucified or their hands and their feet be cut off from opposite sides, or be exiled from the land. That is their disgrace in this world, and a great torment is theirs in the Hereafter”

[al-Maaidah 5:33] Quran source - https://islamqa.info/en/72338

Also see this:

> The crimes of kidnapping, robbery and transgression of the Muslims’ sanctity by way of open and audacious hostility is a type of muhaarabah (waging war against Allaah and His Messenger) and doing mischief in the land, which deserves the punishment mentioned by Allaah in the verse in al-Maa’idah, whether that aggression is against people’s lives, wealth or honour, or it is scaring wayfarers and cutting off routes (banditry). It makes no difference whether that happens in cities, villages, the desert or the wilderness, as is the correct view of the scholars (may Allaah have mercy on them).  Source - https://islamqa.info/en/41682

Firt Conclusion: the only valid punishment for rape is death, so to say castration is a permanent punishment and is equal to the crime of rape is wrong, firstly:

1. No major sin can be truly expiated or completely compensated in this world, such as a person who burned 6 million jews, that person's crime can never be expiated or compensated in this world. And rape is one of the major sins in this world, and it is on the same list as ***shirk***. so as to say: castration is enough because it is permanent for his lifetime is **completely** wrong. The most enough punishment is **death**. And even more in the hereafter on Allaah almighty's part.

And also: trying to change Allaah's laws is kufr.